# Meteor - Connecting Database to Form

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteor and have being trying to build a simple app where a user submits some data and it gets added to a database. I am having two problems:

1) How can I confirm that data is actually been submitted to the database?
2) As you can see in the HTML I setup a template called {{>TaxiInfo}} that is aimed at confirming that data has been sent to the database and then display it. It currently does not work.

Any help that can be provided is greatly appreciated.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<head>
  <title>taximetro</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <nav class="nav nav-tabs">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>       
    </nav>  

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>TaxiMetro</h1>
        <p>Descubre con quien viajas</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    {{>Search}}

    {{>TaxiInfo}}

    {{>Report}}

  </div>
</body>

<template name="Search">
  <form class="Search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchlicense" placeholder="Digita la placa: Ej: ABC123">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" id="searchbutton ">Buscar</button>  
    </div>
  </form>
</template>  

<template name="Report">
  <form class="Report">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="licenseplate">Placa</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control licenseplate" name="licenseplate" id="licenseplate" placeholder="Ingresa la place del vehiculo. Ej: ABC123">
      <label for="review">Escribe tu reseña</label>
      <textarea class="form-control review" name="review" id="review" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default form-control" id="submitbutton" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>  
</template>  

<template name="TaxiInfo">  
      {{#each all_drivers}}
        <p>{{licenseplate}}</p>
        <p>{{review}}</p>
      {{/each}}
</template>
```

The Meteor JS code is as follows:

```
TaxiReviews = new Mongo.Collection('taxidrivers');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.Report.events({
        'click .submit': function () {
            TaxiReviews.insert ({
                licenseplate: $('.licenseplate').val(),
                review: $('.review').val() 
            });
        $('.licenseplate').val('');
        $('.review').val('');       
        }
    });

    Template.TaxiInfo.helpers = function () {
        TaxiReviews.find();
    }
}   

if (Meteor.isServer) {

}
```

Comment: Your jQuery is wrong. You've got `click .submit` but there is no class `submit` anywhere in your HTML. You can try `click #submitbutton`. Usually when debugging events you should first check to see if the event is even being fired by putting a `console.log` or `debugger` in your event handler function. Also, `Collection.insert` will return the unique ID of the document that was inserted if it was successful - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert - You can also check out GenghisApp for a nice little GUI for looking inside your MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks @fuzzybabybunny. Should have paid more attention to my selector. I am looking at GenghisApp and it looks like it suits future and current needs. Question that I can´t find an answer to from their site, does it allow editing of the database? Or is there another app to do that.

Comment: Yeah, you can edit documents in the database using GenghisApp, but I don't think there are any batch operations. I use it just for quick visual confirmation of things.